# Best way to scale or normalize this data

Tags: normalization, scales

I have following data:

```
  id  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
0  A   200   300   425   521   750    95   105
1  B     5     2     3     5     8     2     4
2  C    25    70    50    80    35    45    50
3  D  1025   512   750   425   650   225   400
4  E    85    95    45    25    67    85    35
```

I have to get means of all columns to find which columns have higher values and which have lower.

However, if I simply find mean of all columns from above data, values will be more representative of rows `A` and `D`, which have larger numbers. The `B` row will be least contributing to the means.

I think I need to scale each row separately so that the numbers become comparable. What is the best way to correctly scale or normalize above data? Thanks for your insight.

Edit: The rows belong to different students identified by `Id`. Col1 to col7 are subjects. Hence, `col1 to col7` can be replaced with: `English, Maths, Physics, Chemistry, Biology, Geography, Economics`.  Values in table are the marks obtained. The marks are on different scales since the students are from different schools. I am trying to find out this: "`What are the strong areas (subjects) of this group of students so that appropriate assignment can be given to this group.`"

Comment: There is no answer independent of knowing what these data are. If columns are expressed in the same units and genuinely comparable, then it's not a problem that some values are high and some low. That is just what you are trying to summarize. Conversely, you have not said one word on why you need to make the scales comparable. But if you do that, then the questions of which columns are higher or lower disappears or becomes meaningless. Even if it's a good idea to scale, how can there be good advice on the best way to do it in total abstraction? Your question thus seems very unclear.

Comment: I have clarified the background in question above.

Comment: I don't think you get a better handle on strong and weak areas by throwing away information on the level of each variable.

Answer (score 1):

What you do will depend on what the data is.

If e.g. rows are grades in tests and columns are students, then you should simply scale all of them to [0,1] (for instance) using the min and max grades for each test, then you can compute statistics for each student.

Slightly more generally, assuming each row is a feature and each column a realisation, you can [standardise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) the rows using several methods. Often one subtracts the sample mean and divides by the sample standard deviation. However, computing means across features (i.e. column-wise) will probably make little sense in general.

Comment: Second paragraph is a mystery. Most analyses of grades require taking them as they come. The question of why you should scale at all needs focus. On a different note, there is an identifier column in the example, so I read the columns as being features.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for you correction about stddev, you are of course right. I also hadn't paid attention to the "id" label for the first column, which definitely seems to indicate that columns are features. As to the reasons for standardisation, that's why I linked to WP, there being several, often heuristic. I thought it better to link to a source where to begin reading than doing a poor job of explaining myself. :)

Comment: I have clarified the background in question above.

Answer (score 1):

If you normalize then you will lose the ability to find the answer to your question:

> "What are the strong areas (subjects) of this group of students...?"

When you have scores on different ranges, you can use the geometric mean of each column. This is given by

$$ GM = \prod_{i = 1}^n{x_i}^{1/n}$$

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/measures-of-central-tendency-the-geometric-mean/) about using this mean for just this sort of problem

Comment: Although this point is useful to demonstrate there is more than one way to average data, it doesn't really solve the problem.  Why should the GM be any better than the AM, or rescaling the rows, or any other procedure?

Comment: Can you explain why `"If you normalize then you will lose the ability to find the answer"` Why should I lose this ability if all rows are normalize separately to a range of 0-1 (or 0-100).

Comment: You lose the ability to find the answer because you have gotten rid of the variation that you wish to examine.